# Why do we use nuclide mass in nuclear reactions instead of nucleus mass?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

Why do we use nuclide mass in nuclear reactions instead of nucleus mass in the calculation?

When trying to find the energy released in a nuclear reaction, the mass difference is calculated and put into the $E=mc^2$ formula.

This mass difference is usually calculated by using the nuclide mass (the mass of nucleons + electrons) and not the nucleus mass. Why is that the case considering the fact that in nuclear reactions it is only the nuclei which are reacting?

Comment: Well, you do have things like electron capture or beta decay. As long as you account for all the pieces you are good…

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by accounting for all the pieces? Why are the electrons included in the mass in the first place?

Comment: Well, in electron capture an electron gets ‘eaten’ by the nucleus so you need to account for that in your mass balance. If you only consider the protons and neutrons you are off by 511 keV in mass/energy on one side of your energy balance.

Comment: But why do we consider electrons’ mass in other nuclear reactions where there is no electron capture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mass spectrometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry) can be used to very accurately find the relative **atomic** (actually ionic and a correction can then be made) masses compared to a Carbon-$12$ **atom**.

The difference between the atomic mass and the nuclear mass is the atomic binding
energy of the electrons plus the rest mass of the electron.  The binding energy of the electrons is comparatively small (∼eVs to keVs) as compared with nuclear binding energies (∼MeVs) and nearly balance out on as the term occurs on both sides of a decay equation.